# ZMQ detect client unavailability with heartbeat

Tags: zeromq, heartbeat

I am experiencing with zmq, but I could not find an answer in the docs and examples that the proper use of the following socket options:

- ZMQ_HEARTBEAT_IVL
- ZMQ_HEARTBEAT_TIMEOUT
- ZMQ_HEARTBEAT_TTL

The documentation states that they can be used with any socket types ("when using connection-oriented transports"). Is there a way to use them with REQ/REP socket pairs?

Test client code:

```
zmq::context_t context( 1 );
zmq::socket_t client( context, ZMQ_REQ );
client.connect( "tcp://localhost:5555" );

// Send request.
std::string request( "test message" );
zmq::message_t message( string.size() );
memcpy( message.data(), string.data(), string.size() );
socket.send( message, flags );

// Wait for reply.
socket.recv( &message );

// Do some work that takes cca 10 secs.
// ...

delete client;
```

Test server code:

```
zmq::context_t context( 1 );
zmq::socket_t server( context, zmq::socket_type::rep );

//server.set( zmq::sockopt::rcvtimeo, 5000 );
server.set( zmq::sockopt::heartbeat_ivl, 1000 );
server.set( zmq::sockopt::heartbeat_timeout, 3000 );
server.set( zmq::sockopt::heartbeat_ttl, 3000 );

server.bind( "tcp://*:5555" );

// Wait for request.
zmq::message_t message;
server.recv( &message );

// Send reply.
zmq::message_t message2("Test reply.", 11);
server.send( message);

// Wait for new request.
server.recv( &message );

// ...
```

My goal is to end the server side after the client is done. Socket option `zmq::sockopt::rcvtimeo` works well, it closes the connection on the server side. I thought that the heartbeat socket options would cause something similar, I mean close the server after the client has finished its job and not earlier. I tried them in all possible combinations on both server and client sides, but the server side always gets stuck in the second `recv` opretation.
Checking the localhost network traffic with Wireshark tells that the ping-pong messages are delivered, but that's all.

So my questions are:

- Can these socket options be used in a REQ/REP connection?
- If yes, then how? Which side shall set these socket options?
- If no, then what socket types are recommended?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it looks like you need to use the zmq_socket_monitor() function. That causes the context to create itself a ZMQ_PAIR socket which it will bind to the endpoint you specify. You have to create your own ZMQ_PAIR socket, and connect it to that endpoint too.

You can read event messages from your ZMQ_PAIR socket (see the api reference for how these messages are formatted). So you can include that PAIR socket in a call to zmq_poll(), thus your application can be asynchronously informed when there is a change of status in the socket that you referred to in the zmq_socket_monitor() call.

The event that will be reported for a heartbeat timeout is, I think, ZMQ_EVENT_DISCONNECTED.

See [here](http://api.zeromq.org/master:zmq-socket-monitor).

I'd say that, to get the most value out of this, you're pretty much obliged to use zmq_poll() (or similar). For example, a client expecting to receive messages can't be both blocked on a call to zmq_recv() from the socket connected to the server, and also blocked on the zmq_recv() from the monitor ZMQ_PAIR socket. Whereas if you're blocked on a call to zmq_poll() that's waiting for both the server and monitor sockets, then that'll return either when there is a message from the server, or some problem has arisen that means you're not going to get the message.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I started to read about socket monitoring and the linked page gave me the hint that it might worth replacing the REC/REQ sockets to DEALER/DEALER.

Comment: @Terrordrone, no problem. Yes, the server can monitor the REP socket (or whatever socket type you use to connect to the client) to find out when the client has disconnected. Good luck!

Comment: I managed to make things work with socket monitoring. Thank you again!